# ¿Se dice "echar cuentas" o "hechar cuentas"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, ortografía

Una duda me ha surgido en una conversación. Estamos hablando de que después del evento haremos las cuentas para dividir proporcionalmente.

¿Se dice "echar cuentas" o "hechar cuentas"?

En principio "hechar" lleva "h" cuando es del verbo hacer y "echar" sin h es de "dejar caer una cosa".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> En principio "hechar" lleva "h" cuando es del verbo hacer y "echar" sin h es de "dejar caer una cosa".

No es del todo cierto. [Echar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EJtx4Yo) no lleva hache. No existe un verbo "*hechar*" con hache, aunque esa terminación nos haga pensar que es un infinitivo válido.

[Echar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EJtx4Yo) tiene unas 50 entradas en el diccionario, con significados que van desde "darle impulso a algo para que llegue a otro lado" hasta otros coloquialismos como

> 25. tr. Junto con algunos nombres, tiene la significación de los verbos que se forman de ellos o la de otros equivalentes. Echar maldiciones, maldecir; echar suertes, sortear; echar un cigarro, fumarlo; echar un sueño, dormir; echar la siesta, sestear.
> 26. intr. Dar principio a una acción. Echar a reír, a correr.

y especialmente relevante en este caso

> 19. tr. **Hacer cálculos, cuentas.**

Creo que la confusión que tienes es no por "hechar/echar" si no por "hecho/echo".

- "echo" sería un conjugación de "echar"

> Yo **echo** de comer al perro por la noche

- "hecho" lo es de "hacer"

> Mira lo que he **hecho** con el dinero de la herencia.

Diríamos que yo "**echo** cuentas" pero que "**he hecho** unas cuentas", porque aunque los dos verbos tengan el sentido de "realizar", cuando usas "haber" vas a tener que usar el verbo como participio, y con forma auxiliar.

Comment: Se llaman homónimos cuando dos palabras se escriben o suenan igual. Cuando se escriben distinto y suenan igual se llaman homófonos y cuando se escriben igual y no significan lo mismo se llaman homógrafos.

Echo/hecho son homófonos. Lo mismo que hay y ay, haya y halla, etc.

Es una confusión normal cuando uno no sabe el origen de la palabra y no entiende su significado. Se dice echar cuentas pues no existe verbo hechar. Simple.

Answer (score 5):

La palabra ⓧ *hechar* no existe, pero sí existe [*echar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EJtx4Yo) con múltiples acepciones. Una de ellas es específica para esto:

> **echar**
>   Del lat. iactāre.
>
> 19. tr. Hacer cálculos, cuentas.

Answer (score 0):

Es llamativo que los diccionarios sobre el español estándar no incluyan una acepción muy común en Andalucía.
**Echar cuentas** a alguien significa prestar atención, atender, tener en cuenta a otra persona cuando habla o actúa. Es una locución fraseológica construida a partir del verbo "echar", no del verbo "hacer". 
Probablemente su origen se remonte a la sabiduría popular sobre los avatares o el destino de una persona, como "echar las cartas" a alguien. Pero es mera suposición.

Comment: Echar significa tirar, lanzar, colocar también: echar al fuego, echar los dados, echarse al suelo, echar las cartas, echar de la casa, echarse encima, etc.

Comment: @walen: La 10ª acepción de "cuenta" es: Consideración o atención. Buscando en el CREA "echar cuenta" (en singular) encuentras por ejemplo "...puesto que yo estaba medio chuchurrío y desganado, no iba a **echar cuenta** de nada y ..."  (Mendicutti, Eduardo: El palomo cojo (1991)) y para "echar cuentas", por ejemplo: "... metió en la cama a Don Juanito desde que llegó, y cuando fueron a **echar cuentas** lo tenía como un arenque..." (Martínez Mediero, Manuel: Juana del amor hermoso (1982)). En los dos casos interpreto que el significado es  **prestar atención, darse cuenta**.

Comment: @walen: Mea culpa. Pensé que aunque Joaquín indica que es un uso no recogido en el diccionario, podría estar errado. Tienes toda la razón en que los ejemplos no son apropiados para el uso que él indica.